# How do I compute the variance of expected number of fair coin flips for HTH sequence using linear system of equations?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Assuming fair coin flips, I know how to compute the expected number of coin flips to see HTH sequence by writing out the linear system of equations from the state transition diagram below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3YGa.png

Define $E(X)$ as the expected number of steps from state X to state HTH. E(0) means expected number of steps to get from state 0 to state HTH and E(H) means expected number of steps to get from state H to state HTH, etc. I'd like out the equations with the transition probability and expected value of the neighbor state plus one for the immediate step. The full linear system of equations is as follows.

\begin{align}
E(0) &= \frac{1}{2} (E(H) + 1) + \frac{1}{2} (E(0) + 1)\\
E(H) &= \frac{1}{2} (E(H) + 1) + \frac{1}{2} (E(HT) + 1)\\
E(HT) &= \frac{1}{2} (E(HTH) + 1) + \frac{1}{2} (E(0) + 1)\\
E(HTH) &= 0
\end{align}

We can solve for $E(0)$ since we have 4 equations and 4 unknowns. It turns out $E(0)=10$

**The question is how do we compute the variance** $V(0)$. I understand that we can build the transition matrix and use the one line matrix formula from Wikipedia. However, I'm interested in intuitive system of equations approach (without any of Markov chain jargons like fundamental matrix, ergodic, transient, etc) just like the one I wrote above to compute $E(0)$. My hunch is we need systems of equations defined with $E(X^2)$ variables but it's not clear to me how to approach that.

Comment: The method is quite general: find the linear system solved by $u_s(x)=E_x(s^N)$ where $N$ is the number of steps needed to produce HTH starting from $x$ and $s$ is a parameter such that $|s|\leqslant1$. This is quite similar to the system for the quantities $e(x)=E_x(N)$ that you recalled in your question, in particular $x$ is in the set of *prefixes* of the word HTH, that is, in $\{\varnothing,$H,HT,HTH$\}$, but now the system is different. Once $E_\varnothing(s^N)$ is known, differentiate this function of $s$ once and twice at $s=1$ to get $E_\varnothing(N)$ and $E_\varnothing(N(N-1))$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint but could you please elaborate? I don't understand the intuition about the expression $E_x(s^N)$. Is this $s$ raised to power $N$? What does this ($s^N$ and expectation of $s^N$) mean? If you could help me get started, I'll try to work out the details and report.

Comment: ?? Yes $s^N$ is $s$ to the power $N$ and $E(s^N)$ is the expectation of $s^N$.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't very clear. I don't understand what $s^N$ and expectation of $s^N$ signifies and it's difficult to get started on what system of equations I should be writing. Could you please provide some description or a couple of equations so I can understand the intuition about your approach?

Comment: Sorry but if $s$ is some real number and $N$ some random variable, then $s^N$ is a problem? How comes?

Comment: I meant to ask what $s$ or $s^N$ intuitively means/encodes. For me, it's difficult to write down equations that you hinted without understanding any meaning/encodings behind the variables. For example in my original question, X encodes different states: H, HT, etc. E(X) encodes expected number of steps till the final state(HTH) starting from state X. Did I make my question more clear?

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain the variance we have to count more carefully. Again we have to consider the states $0$, $H$, $HT$, and $HTH$. Denote the probability that in state $H$ the game is over in exactly $k$ additional moves by $p_H(k)$, and define $p_0(k)$, $p_{HT}(k)$, $p_{HTH}(k)$ similarly. Then we have to solve the system
$$\eqalign{
p_0(k)&={1\over2}p_H(k-1)+{1\over2}p_0(k-1) \cr
p_H(k)&={1\over2}p_{HT}(k-1)+{1\over2}p_H(k-1) \cr
p_{HT}(k)&={1\over2}p_{HTH}(k-1)+{1\over2}p_0(k-1)\cr
p_{HTH}(k)&=\delta_{0k}\cr}$$
along the lines of the "Master Theorem" and will then have an explicit expression for $k\mapsto p_0(k)$. This will allow to compute what you call $V(0)$.

Comment: More complicated than needed when, like the OP, only the moments are desired.

Comment: @Did: I read "I understand that we can build the transition matrix and use the one line matrix formula from Wikipedia. However, I'm interested in intuitive system of equations approach (without any of Markov chain jargons like fundamental matrix, ergodic, transient, etc) just like the one I wrote above to compute $E(0)$." – So far nobody has proposed a simpler approach.

Comment: "So far nobody has proposed a simpler approach." See my comment.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: `Did`'s comments were incomprehensible so I pursued your suggestion. I've got $p_0(0)=p_0(1)=p_0(2)=0$, $p_0(3)=p_0(4)=\frac{1}{2^3}$, $p_0(5)=\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^4}$, $p_0(k \geq 6) = \frac{1}{2}p_0(k-1) + \frac{1}{4}p_0(k-2)+\frac{1}{2^k}$. I'm not an expert on master theorem. Could you please give some insight on how to proceed further?